# Java iText Geospatial PDF exporter

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, geospatial

I'm planning to use Java iText library to generate Geospatial PDF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF).

There are some basic support in iText, but I have not found any high level API. People are trying to directly use the adobe format extensions.

http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg40443.html

Do you know any easier solution?

Thanks in advance, Regards,

Answer (score 5):

Until iText adds some high-level API calls for it, your only option will be to dive into the low level objects (PdfObject's subclasses) with a copy of the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) handy, turned to the relevant section...

err... Must be in one of the addendums... [Ah!  Here it is.](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf), under "part 1:..."->Interactive Features...->8.8 Measurement Properties->8.8.1 Geospatial Features.

I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I knew that (is what we tried), but it will be very useful for people who reads the question.